# "A bonus for/of the same amount"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

> 1. One group was taxed a Benjamin if they didn't do X, and the second was given a bonus **of** *the same amount* for doing X.
> 2. One group was taxed $100 if they didn't do X, and the second was given a bonus **for** *the same amount* if they did X.

I guess both options are valid but I'm wonderig which one is more natural to (mostly) American eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, firstly, being taxed "a Benjamin" is highly colloquial, in case you're not aware of that.

As for "for" vs. "of", "of" is much more correct to me. I'm not even sure if "for" is correct at all.